# How to "draw" UIImages into a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I am making a simple game, but I need it to draw images twenty times every second. I was going to use multiple UIImageViews, but I quickly realized that it would not work. So, how can a draw images, then "erase" them when the update timer fires? I tried to use the following code, but nothing showed up.

```
- (void) update:(NSTimer*) timer {
    UIimage *someImage;
    someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];
    [someImage drawAtPoint:thePoint];
}
```

I have tried to make thePoint both an NSPoint and a CGRect, but nothing showed up. What do I do now? Note: thePoint is declared in my .h file. It is currently an NSPoint, and I think it is being used properly.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with using image views in this sort of situation, but wouldn't you be able to set the images into one imageView instance?  When the update occurs, you could call `imageView.image = nil;` then set the new image with `imageView.image = newImage;`.  Provided the image size isn't large (forcing the imageView to scale it), it should theoretically be able to set the images in time

Comment: If it's an animation you are trying to do (play several frames at a given frame rate) this is not the way you should do it. Use instead `yourView.animationImages = animationFramesArray;
    yourView.animationDuration = 10;
    [yourView startAnimating];`

Comment: @mindnoise It is not an animation, but thank you for telling me how to do that. That will be extremely useful later when I start adding animations to something in another app I am planning on making.

Comment: This implementation with image views might not prove suitable in terms of performance. I'd opt out for CALayer subclass and draw images directly into context in drawInContext method. One reason for doing it this way is loading image data and drawing image directly into context can save you from nasty features that lurk behind UIImage and UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

Is this really your code? It makes almost no sense. You've made a local variable, `someImage`, haven't created an object for it to point to, and are then trying to call a method on this non-object that doesn't exist on the class you're trying to use (`UIImage` has no `setImage:`). It's almost guaranteed to crash, and if it doesn't right away, then it very well might cause one later because it's clobbering memory -- a variable created on the stack like this doesn't get initialized to 0 (`nil`) as it would if it were an ivar, and trying to send a message to some random address is a bad idea. Why would you try passing a `CGRect` to a method that even says *in its name* that it takes a point? Finally, where do you expect this to be drawn? You need a drawing context (usually provided by a view, which is mentioned in your title, but not the question) for drawing to go into.

Please have a look at the ["Images"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW1) chapter of the Drawing Guide, if nothing else.

Comment: Umm...someImage means I will just use an image... it isnt actually a UIImage. In my real code, I used [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"] instead.

Comment: Then why does your question state "I tried to use the following code:"?! Please post your _real_ code. How can we help you if you don't tell us what you're actually doing?

Comment: I thought I made it clear. I will edit my code to show what I did. Thank you for bringing up that point.

Comment: @Justin, I realize that I may have sounded a little raving in this post, and I apologize, but this updated code _still doesn't make sense_. `UIImage` ***doesn't have a method*** called `setImage:` Don't you see the warning when you try to build?

Comment: I am sorry; I guess I made a mistake. I will fix that, and try running it again.

Comment: It kinda worked. I don't get any warnings, and it does not crash. Unfortunately, I am not getting any images to show up, even with the code in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`NSPoint` is for Mac, and `CGRect` is, well, a rectangle and not a point.  What you're looking for is a `CGPoint`.  Try something like this:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimer*) timer {
    CGPoint thePoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];
    [someImage drawAtPoint:thePoint];
}
```

Comment: This is a good **point** <ahem!>, but there still needs to be a drawing context.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't make that lucid.  I was trying to make this point  *(cough)* in addition to yours.